# degree of isogeny understanding

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

In the context below why is the degree of the Frobenius endomorphism p ?
[image]

Comment: Frobenius composed with its dual is multiplication by $p$ (hence has degree $p^2$), so Frobenius has degree $p$.

Comment: Can you explain above ? The paper that I am reading defines the degree of isogeny as folllows sogeny is defined by an irreducible polynomial, we define the degree of an isogeny as the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: what is the definition of degree of isogeny can you maybe explain in an answer ?

Comment: if $C,C'$ are curves over a field $K$, the degree of a non-constant morphism $C\to C'$ is defined as the degree of the induced field extension $K(C')\subseteq K(C)$.